# How safe is it to use a Github Action contributed by a third party?

Tags: trust, opensource

I'm considering using a Github Action from the Github Marketplace to back up some of my source code to an AWS S3 bucket.

My question is this: I found a Github Action, written by a third-party open source contributor, with its source code available on Github.  Should I be concerned about the security of this arrangement?

- What would prevent the contributor from giving access to the Github Action source repo to someone else (potentially a malicious actor) who could then modify the action code?
- Does Github validate that these contributed Actions are not malicious and do only what they claim to do?
- If so, do they validate this each time a code change is made to the Action repo?  Each time that a new version of the Action is released?

I'm concerned that a malicious actor could modify the Github Action code unbeknownst to me and copy my source code to a location of their choosing.

Comment: If you are concerned about modifications to the GitHub repository that contains the action why don't you just fork this repo and use it. Then it is under your control who can change the action code. See also https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2021/02/06/GitHub-Actions-Forking-Repositories

Comment: It is free software.  If it breaks, you get both pieces.  If you are paranoid about what it does, review the code, and review any changes in updates.  Make sure you read the licenses that come with it.

Comment: I found @Robert 's article to be useful in addressing these concerns.

Answer (score -1):

To mitigate the risk of a malicious action stealing your source code, you can consider using our https://github.com/step-security/harden-runner to enable network egress filtering to prevent outbound traffic to unknown destinations.

We recently published a blog post around third-party GitHub Actions governance covering various aspects like reviewing the actions and strategies to minimize risks. I believe this could offer some valuable insights and practical tips for your concern.
https://www.stepsecurity.io/blog/github-actions-security-best-practices

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This just appears to be a pointer to your project and blog. We try not to have answers like "here, use this!" Instead, explain the concepts and approaches and use your product as an *example* alongside other products. Else, it becomes an ad. We have vendors here that do that very well without sounding like a self-promotion.